# How to add a new column in CSV file at the end of all columns using gsub in Unix?

Tags: linux, csv, unix, awk, gsub

Original test file:

[image: original test file]

I want to add a new column (CSV filename) at the end of all columns in a CSV file using awk and gsub functions in Unix.

Input data (filename test.csv):

```
col1,col2,col3
ab,  cd,  ef
gh,  ij,  kl
mn,  op,qr
```

Output file should look like:

```
col1,col2,col3,test.csv
ab,cd,ef,test.csv
gh,ij,kl,test.csv
mn,op,qr,test.csv
```

I have tried with below code:

```
awk '{gsub(/ /,",",$0);print $0,",",FILENAME > "test.csv"}' test.csv
```

Using this, the file name is getting appended at second column instead of last column:

[image: tested result file]

It works fine with .txt files but doesn't work with .csv files; my requirement is to handle both type of file to append file name at the end.

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you want to use `gsub()`? [edit] your question to provide answers.

Comment: Most likely you have DOS line breaks in your input file. Just remove it using `{sub(/\r$/, "")}` before `gsub` block.

Comment: it worked! , thanks Anubhava
Appreciate every ones inputs!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some demonstrated effort would have been nice, but:

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/ /,"");print $0","FILENAME}' test.csv 
col1,col2,col3,test.csv
ab,cd,ef,test.csv
gh,ij,kl,test.csv
mn,op,qr,test.csv
```

Redirect the output to a temporary file and then replace the original with it.

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/ /,"");print $0","FILENAME}' test.csv > tmp.csv && mv tmp.csv test.csv && cat test.csv
col1,col2,col3,test.csv
ab,cd,ef,test.csv
gh,ij,kl,test.csv
mn,op,qr,test.csv
```

Comment: I am getting same results, filename appending in second column instead of last column

Comment: Guss tour data looks different from what you posted, then? @Surya

Comment: Just to give more insight i have created a sample file to test

Comment: So this (according to your comment on the question) now works? No more DOS line endings? Feel free to accept the answer, then.